# Substring or split word in clamp

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, substring

I need an solution for my problem. I have a clause like:

> Hello guys I am cool (test)

An now I need an effective method to split just only the part in the parentheses and the result should be:

> test

My try is to split the String in words like. But I don't think it is the best way.

```
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
```

Comment: When you say clamp I assume you mean bracket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that split is the solution to your problem

Regex is very good for extracting data.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpression;
...
string result = Regex.Match(s, @"\((.*?)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
var input = "Hello guys I am cool (test)";
```

..Non-Regex version:

```
var nonRegex = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('(') + 1, input.LastIndexOf(')') - (input.IndexOf('(') + 1));
```

..Regex version:

```
var regex = Regex.Match(input, @"\((\w+)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this:

```
string parenthesized = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))").Value;
```

Here's an explanation of the various parts of the regex pattern:

- `(?<=\()`: Lookbehind for the `(` (excluded from the match)
- `[^)]+`: Sequence of characters consisting of anything except `)`
- `(?=\))`: Lookahead for the `)` (excluded from the match)

Comment: I need just only test as solution-String

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is using string methods but you don't need `Split` but `Substring` and `IndexOf`.  Note that this currently just finds a single word in parentheses:

```
string text = "Hello guys I am cool (test)";
string result = "--no parentheses--";
int index = text.IndexOf('(');
if(index++ >= 0) // ++ used to look behind ( which is a single character
{
    int endIndex = text.IndexOf(')', index);
    if(endIndex >= 0)
    {
        result = text.Substring(index, endIndex - index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really think this solution is much faster than simple regex? Have you performed/seen any benchmarks? Without them it looks like micro optmization in cost of readiblity...

Comment: @KonradKokosa: OP mentioned _effective_ and used string methods. That's why i've provided `Substring`. It depends on the size of the text or how often you use this method of course. But even if it doesn't make a difference it's good to know how it works with string methods only.

Comment: I just wonders how many billion times calls it would make a difference in terms of efficiency between this and regex. Of course it is good to know this alternative.

Answer (score -2):

```
string s = "Hello guys I am cool (test)";
var result = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("test"), 4);
```

Comment: This code is effectively equivalent to just writing `var result = "test"`. You should assume that the OP wants to match other strings in the parentheses.

Comment: I downvoted. The OP's requirement is to match _whatever_ is between the parenthesis. This simply finds "test".